# Why is there no LWC lightning-list-view?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components

There is an Aura [lightning:listView](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:listView/documentation), but presently not a LWC `lightning-list-view`. For most Aura components there is an LWC equivalent. That allows the <strike>composting</strike> composing of LWCs inside other LWCs which is a great way to leverage what has already been built rather than having to start from scratch.

Why no LWC in this case?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

While looks there is no component which is very similar to aura version there is api thats of BETA quality.

There is a [lightning/uiListApi](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_lightning_ui_api_list_ui) module to get List views data and metadata in LWC. Note that as of today it is under BETA.

There is also a sample code in the trailhead recipe [repo](https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/blob/master/force-app/main/default/lwc/wireListView/wireListView.js)

```
import { LightningElement, wire } from 'lwc';
import { getListUi } from 'lightning/uiListApi';

import CONTACT_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/Contact';
import NAME_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Contact.Name';

export default class WireListView extends LightningElement {
 @wire(getListUi, {
    objectApiName: CONTACT_OBJECT,
    listViewApiName: 'All_Recipes_Contacts',
    sortBy: NAME_FIELD,
    pageSize: 10
})
listView;

 get contacts() {
    return this.listView.data.records.records;
 }
}
```

You can combine this with the `lightning-datatable` to get one similar to the list view.

Comment: Thanks Mohith. No word on a `lightning-list-view`? Any idea why not?

Comment: @keith No word on it but I will let you know once I hear something on it.

Comment: As a note, "lightning/uiListApi" is deprecated as of time of writing, and as per SF documentation, may cease to work in the future

Comment: But there's the lightning/uiListsApi https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_lightning_ui_api_lists_ui

Answer (score -1):

Looks like there is this now, putting this here to help other folks searching for the answer! https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:listView/documentation

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/206788)

Comment: That is the Aura component; was looking for an LWC equivalent.