# How to fetch Account records in lightning datatable using @wire but without using Apex class

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter

I am new to LWC, and I am trying to build lightning datatable using lightning ui* adaptor and **@wire method to **display Account records as a list view but without using Apex controller****

I have used lightning/uiObjectInfoApi module but it is fetching only fields name not records list

Can anyone help me please
Thanks

Comment: @NagendraSingh it will fetch one single record with recordId parameter, I want to display Account list view

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is there no LWC lightning-list-view?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/300889/why-is-there-no-lwc-lightning-list-view)

Comment: They are using lightning/uiListApi and that is deprecated
I have tried latest that is not deprecated - lightning/uiListsApi but it only display field/column names

Answer (score 1):

You need to use GraphQL wire adaptor which can directly access your salesforce data using having to write apex methods.

> If you go for getting list view using UI Adaptors, It does not give
> you flexibility to have your own set of fields and filters.

The [GraphQL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/reference_graphql) wire adapter manages your data using Lightning Data Service (LDS). You don’t need different wire adapters for each query defined in the GraphQL schema, unlike the other wire adapters. Instead, LDS provides a single wire adapter that accepts a GraphQL query document and a variables map.

A working example from [docs](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_lwc_graphql_wire.htm&release=242&type=5) is:-

```
import { LightningElement, wire } from 'lwc';
import { gql, graphql } from 'lightning/uiGraphQLApi';

export default class ExampleGQL extends LightningElement {
    @wire(graphql, {
        query: gql`
            query AccountInfo {
                uiapi {
                    query {
                        Account(where: { Name: { like: "United%" } }) @category(name: "recordQuery") {
                            edges {
                                node {
                                    Name @category(name: "StringValue") {
                                        value
                                        displayValue
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }`
    })
    propertyOrFunction
}
```

Check out these example on LWC Recipies:-

1. https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/tree/main/force-app/main/default/lwc/graphqlContacts
2. https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/tree/main/force-app/main/default/lwc/graphqlMultipleObjects
3. https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/tree/main/force-app/main/default/lwc/graphqlPagination